# how to make a formated print of list with list within it in python

Tags: python, list, printing

I have a class in python with 2 "main" strings and a list of strings in it with N size

How can I "nicely" format the print of it so i can print the pain list and it will look normal.

The expected result is like:

```
entry 1 : string1 string 2 <br>
liststring1 liststring2 .... liststring n

entry 2 : string1 string 2 <br>
liststring1 liststring2 .... liststring n

.<br>
.<br>
.<br>
entry n : string1 string 2 <br>
liststring1 liststring2 .... liststring n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's presume your python class, `Entry`, has the following member variables:

```
Entry.string1  
Entry.string2  
Entry.list_of_strings
```

Then to print a `list_of_entries`:

```
>>> for entry in list_of_entries:
...     print entry, " : ", entry.string1, entry.string2
...     for s in entry:
...         print s,
...     print ""
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> for entry in l:
...    print entry, ":", 
...    for x in entry:
...        print x,
...    print
```

Notice the trailing commas in `print` statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [pprint](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) module for easy printing of 2D lists, among other things.

```
import pprint
x=[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],['jkdfjkdfjkfdjkfdkjfdkdfjfkdjdkfjkdjkfd']]
pprint.pprint(x)
```